# When to use `...length()` versus `rlang::dots_n(...)`?

Tags: r, rlang, ellipsis

In a function, I have to count the number of parameters that are passed through the ellipsis.

I always used `...length()` so far, but I recently became aware of `rlang::dots_n(...)`.

They seem to yield the same output in my tests so far:

```r
f = function(x=1, ...){
  print(paste0("base::...length() = ", ...length()))
  print(paste0("rlang::dots_n() = ", rlang::dots_n(...)))
}
f(a=1, b=2, d)
#> [1] "base::...length() = 2"
#> [1] "rlang::dots_n() = 2"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I expect that rlang devs would not create a function that adds no benefit over a base function, but there is no mention of `...length()` in `help(dots_n)` to outline a comparison.

Is there any significant difference I am not aware of that could prevent or add some bugs?

Comment: For what it’s worth, ‘rlang’ has some functions that are entirely redundant with core R functionality, to be able to provide a more consistent interface. `dots_n()` *does* add some functionality (because you can pass additional arguments, not just `...`, and it will also count these) but whether that functionality is useful is up to you to decide. In fact, [the implementation of `dots_n()`](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/blob/84deb877d1ce4ba50fbaafea246c1eb918805631/R/dots.R#L395-L397) is simply calling `nargs()`.

Comment: Oh, that's actually a pretty disturbing interface, don't you think? Wouldn't writing `dots_n(c(..., y=5))` be against the very sense of the function's name?

Comment: How is `dots_n` supposed to know that the first elements came from the dots after the interpreter evaluates the `c` arguments?

Comment: @IRTFM that's exactly my point, you can use `dots_n()` in a way that it doesn't count the number of variables in the dots. You cannot use `...length()` in such a way and it makes much more sense to me.

Comment: Sorry that I missed your point.